# loading controllers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

For register page I have 'Register' controller

For login page, I have 'login' controller

I loaded url, form helpers

at the end of I have given login link as follows

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>login">Login</a>
```

But it's showing the error.

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: `<?= base_url() ?>/login`

Comment: not working brother

Comment: do you use htaccess ?

Comment: have you set the baseurl? what have you set it to? what is the function currently echoing

Comment: Controller first character must in capital letter. i.e.Login.php

Comment: In config file base_url() is empty

Comment: yes i saved Login.php and class name also Login

Comment: @Raghavendra Naidu set url in **$config['base_url']** in application\config\config.php

Comment: @Dave bro, i am working in localhost. please let me know how to change

Comment: @Raghavendra Naidu **$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/your_folder_name/';**  in application\config\config.php

Comment: Try to access login controller directly in browser as `localhost/your_ci/login` then also it gives error, then try `localhost/your_ci/index.php/login`. Check what you getting.

Comment: @nagesh katke bro i try with localhost/your_ci/index.php/login  then its showing the login form

Comment: but i  removed index.php in config file

Comment: @RaghavendraNaidu then you need to set your base url as `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_ci'` and in view `<a href="<?php echo base_url('login);?>">Login</a>`

Comment: @NageshKatke not working bro

Comment: Try to inspect what is coming in `<a href=''>` in your view.

Comment: <a href="http://localhost/ecom/login">

Comment: Copy that url and paste it in browser, if it don't work then try to add index.php before login. If it works with index.php then you need to change your htaccess and remove index.php from config like `$config['index_page'] = '';` Hope this will help you and works.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `htaccess file` to this. I think it will work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And Base URL should be absolute, including the protocol:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://somesite.com/somedir/";
```

If using the URL helper, then base_url() will output the above string.

Comment: I am working in localhost bro. how to modify that base_url in config file

Comment: Do you load url in autoload.php which is in application/config folder as
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

and in config.php file as
$config['base_url'] = "http://somesite.com/somedir/";

Comment: already loaded. I loaded in controller too. for base_url() i am working in localhost bro

Comment: If I add base url in config file, url is coming like this http://[::1]/ecom/localhost/ecom/login

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ecom/';

Then use in a tag as 
<a href="<?php echo base_url('login');?>">Login</a>

Comment: Can you share your htaccess file content? config.php file also

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Do you try my htaccess content?

BTW your controller name should be Login.php and class name also class Login..Do you check this?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = '';     $config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: I tried all ur suggestions. htaccess, base url in config file

Comment: Where is the content on base_url?
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/ecom/";

Comment: If kept base url as loccalhost/ecom... then after clicking login url becomes http://[::1]/ecom/localhost/ecom/login   so i removed this

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http:// localhost/ ecom/'

put as like this and remove space

Comment: if I try with localhost/ecom/index.php/login then its displaying the login form.

Comment: $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; change to $config['index_page'] = '';
in config.php file under $config['base_url'] you will see

Comment: I change my htaccess..Use it

Answer (score 1):

First Check Your `base_url` From `application/Config/config.php` file

Then Set Your `base_url()`

```
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/[your-project-name]';`
```

if your project have on root folder then set

```
`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';`
```

Note: In Login Controller May be You find index file. If not then must be set your function name. Like this:

```
 <a href="<?php echo base_url('ControllerName/MethodName');?>">Login/[your-function-name]</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('ControllerName/MethodName');?>">Login</a>
```

Comment: i already tried. <?php echo base_url('login/index');?>    I wrote index method inside

Comment: set the base_url in config and url helper in autoload

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed `index.php` from `url` using `.htaccess` file?
If yes the you can use `<?php echo base_url('login'); ?>`.
Or else you should use `<?php echo site_url('login'); ?>`.

Comment: I removed index.php and also changed the htaccess as in the codeigniter offiial website

Comment: By default  url is    http://[::1]/ecom/                 after clicking on login its http://[::1]/ecom/login

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

assuming your `index.php` is in `htdocs` *directly* and not some subfolder.

otherwise it should be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sub_folder/';`

(trailing slash required)